# How to find out the S3 link of an AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have created an AWS AMI that I want to download to my local machine. I understand that AMIs are stored in S3, and that I can use the ec2-download-bundle command from the AMI cli to download it, but I want to know how to find out which S3 bucket my AMI is in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to download it to your local machine? Do you want it to be bootable, or do you just want the data that is stored on there? Would you be willing to simply transfer the data instead of the whole disk?

Comment: I am closing my AWS account but I want to back up the machine state in case I ever re-open my AWS account and want to use the machine. Ideally I want to transfer the whole disk so that I have the installed programs and environment the same, but if its not possible, I am open to just transferring the data.

Answer (score 0):

The AMI's are stored in your account and you pay AMI's storage cost but they aren't really stored in any of your account's s3 bucket. so you can't have specific s3 location to findout these AMI's.

Comment: Almost correct, except the part about storing EBS snapshots. You don't get to pick what S3 bucket those are stored in either, and you don't get access to them either. EBS snapshots plus some metadata are all an AMI really is, and the storage of EBS snapshots and AMIs behave the same way.

Comment: So how do I download the AMI to my local machine then?

Comment: It is not possible to download an AMI. The closest you could do is create an `.iso` image, mount it using an iso-mounting tool, copy the contents across, then download the iso file.

Comment: How do I create a .iso image?